# how to populate to an array inside another shema using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose-schema

There are two collections. Catalog collection and order Collection. Catalog collection contains seller id , and compelete product details.

Order collection contains order details like ids of ordered products and buyer details.

My problem is how can I get the complete product details when fetching  an order  .

order collection is given below

[this is the order collection. It contains product Id. I need to get the details of products when fetching orders. Problem is that there is no seperate collection for products. Products are present inside 'catalog' collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqLLG.jpg)

Catalog Collection is given below:
[this is the catalog collection.It contains an array of products. so the products are present there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmhar.jpg)

I need to get  product details when fetching order details

Answer (score 0):

```
const order = await Order.find().populate("products");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question entirely but hope should help you:

### Plan

1. unwind products
2. lookup product with _id of product in `catalog.products`
3. unwind the lookup result because result of lookup stage is an array
4. group this back together

### Implementation

```js
const result = await orderModel.aggregate()
    .unwind('products')
    .lookup({
      from: 'catalogs',
      let: { product_id: '$products' }, // in order
      pipeline: [
        {
          $unwind: '$products' // $expr cannot digest arrays so we need to unwind which hurts performance...
        },
        {
          $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$products._id', '$$product_id'] } }
        },
        {
          $project: { _id: 0, products: 1 } // only care products in catelog
        }
      ],
      as: 'productDetail'
    })
    .unwind('productDetail')
    .group({
      _id: '$_id',
      seller: { '$first': '$seller' },
      buyer: { '$first': '$buyer' },
      products: {
        $push: '$productDetail.products'
      }
    });
```

However, I don't recommend doing it this way as it can be resource intensive... I suggest you change your database design eg separating product into a separate collection for easier querying.